# Reworking a data structure without recursion

Tags: rust

I want to create a data structure that I can update, but at the same time process. Recursion comes to mind, but I read this is not good in Rust.

I am trying to make a domain scraper, each host URL needs to be added to a `vec`- which holds all relative URLs for the domain. This would then be passed to a HTTP client to run the status checks.

If I use a `Hashmap` to track the page and its list of URLs, I also need to rework that list and update the same data structure - without checking duplication. I do not know the final length of the list, which makes it difficult to add a constraint on a loop.

```
    let init = do_request(url).await;
    let mut pages = process_domain_links(init.as_str(), host).await;
    let mut storage: HashMap<String, Vec<String>> = HashMap::new();
    for u in pages {
        if !storage.contains_key(&u) && u.contains(host) {
            let d = do_request(&u).await;
            let mut list = process_domain_links(&d, host).await;
 
            let url: String = u.to_owned();
            storage.insert(url, list);
        }
    }
   for v in storage.values() {
      // loop through v and process_domain_links
      // update storage, if not key is already checked
   }

pub async fn process_domain_links(res: &str, org: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    let links: HashSet<String> = Document::from(res)
        .find(Name("a"))
        .filter_map(|n| n.attr("href"))
        .map(|n| n.to_owned())
        .collect::<HashSet<String>>();
    let parsed = parse_links(org, links);
    return parsed;
}
```

Any tips for approaching this problem?

Comment: What is `host`?

Comment: Also, there isn't really a formal reason against recursion, if your problem fits a recursion well I don't see a reason against it. The main reason here against a recursion is probably that you can't recursively iterate and modify the same data structure at the same time.

Comment: Yeah this is the issue, I need to both consume but feed the one data structure. I guess I could have some kind of temporary storage, but I think there should be another way. Originally I had the storage as a vec that I could both append new values and run through those same new values as a range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a little trick:

```rust
let mut unprocessed = storage.keys().cloned().collect::<Vec<_>>();
while let Some(key) = unprocessed.pop() {
    // Needs clone() to avoid holding a reference to `storage`
    let v = storage.get(&key).unwrap().clone();

    for u in v {
        if !storage.contains_key(&u) && u.contains(host) {
            let d = do_request(&u).await;
            let list = process_domain_links(&d, host).await;

            let url: String = u.to_owned();
            storage.insert(url.clone(), list);
            unprocessed.push(url);
        }
    }
}
```

If I understand correctly, you only want to process every item in `storage` once. If new items get added to `storage`, you want to process those as well.

Therefore, store all the keys to items that are yet to be processed in a `Vec`. Then, the `storage` variable is free to be tampered with, while you only iterate over `Vec` by popping items one-by-one, meaning you can add values to `Vec` while you iterate over it.

Comment: Yes exactly. You understand the problem correctly, also I think your right about using a `Vec` to store the growing list. Am thinking `unprocessed.pop()` would eventually return false, as the looping continues and less matches occur under the `for` loop, i.e the list starts to shrink??

Comment: Isn't that the goal? To process everything once, and then finish?

Comment: And yes, it will return `None` when there are no more elements in it (not `false`), which will end the loop. It will definitely finish at some point, because you only add new elements you haven't seen before into it, as you do `!storage.contains_key(&u)`.

Comment: Ah yes of course `Option` would be `None`. This looks good thanks. Will try to implement and comment again.

Comment: This was a good solution. thanks @Finomnis

Answer (score 0):

```rust
for v in storage.values_mut() {
    if process(v) {
        *v = something_else;
    }
}
```

[HashMap::values_mut()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.values_mut) returns an iterator of mutable references to the hash map's values